# Can't Access API secured with Oauth 2.0 from Angular

Tags: angular, api, oauth-2.0

I have an Angular project which needs to access a web API secured with OAuth 2.0.

However, I face CORS error while accessing this API.

Please find my code below:

App.module.ts:

```
imports
...
@NgModule({
 declarations: [
  AppComponent
 ],
 imports: [
   BrowserModule,
   AppRoutingModule,
   HttpClientModule,
   AuthModule.forRoot({
      domain: 'https://test/v2/',
      clientId: 'xxx',
      clientSecret: 'xxxxx'
   }),
  ],
  providers: [{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthHttpInterceptor, multi: true },
    AuthService,
    HttpClient
  ],
   bootstrap: [
     AppComponent]
  })
 export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.html

```
 <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" (click)="getInfo()">
   GetInfo
</button>
```

app.component.ts

```
  let responseData = this.http.get('https://test/v2/xxx');
responseData.subscribe(
  response => {
  },
  error => {
    console.log(error)
  }
);
```

I am getting the error below:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://test/v2/xxx' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Please help me.

Kind Regards.

Comment: I hope you don't mind, I removed the "accessibility" tag as that tag is used for topics related to ensuring things are usable by people with disabilities and this question did not seem to fit the tag intentions. Good luck with getting your answer!

Comment: Also your error tells you what to do, you need to set a header on the API side that has the content `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`, you send this header back from your API to the requesting script (`app.component.ts`) See if this article helps you understand https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin